# How can i add existing customer in BCC or CC while sending new customer account creation welcome email in magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, customer-account

How to add some existing customer's emails in BCC or CC in welcome emails  in magento2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send CC AND BCC to customer by below code.

\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\EmailNotification.php

```
private function sendEmailTemplate(
        $customer,
        $template,
        $sender,
        $templateParams = [],
        $storeId = null,
        $email = null
    ) {
        $templateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($template, 'store', $storeId);
        if ($email === null) {
            $email = $customer->getEmail();
        }

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue($sender, 'store', $storeId))
            ->addTo($email, $this->customerViewHelper->getCustomerName($customer))
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
```

Add/replace the below code

```
    $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
        ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
        ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue($sender, 'store', $storeId))
        ->addTo($email, $this->customerViewHelper->getCustomerName($customer))

->addBcc('test@test.com')
->addCc('test@test.com')

        ->getTransport();
```

As well as add the same format(addBcc,addCc) in below files too.

```
module-customer\Model\AccountManagement.php
module-customer\Model\Customer.php
```

> Note : recommended to override by custom module.

Comment: How to override custom module ?

Comment: Create a new module, override the model class in your module.Assume you know the basic module creation.

Comment: Would you change anything with this if you *only* want to have a BCC for the new customer welcome email?

Answer (score 0):

Please take reference from `<magento-root>/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php` for what are the methods available

```
$transport = $this->_tb->setTemplateIdentifier('cart_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo('xxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx')
                ->addBcc('yyyyy@yyyy.yyy')
                ->addCc('zzzzzz@zzzz.zzz')
                ->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: how to add multiple bcc?

Comment: Can you add multiple values in bbc with this way: $emails = ['email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com']. And where ccall bbc, add $emails like this ->addBcc($emails)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple BCC emails, you can add them in foreach

```
$bcc = array(
    'john@doe.com',
    'test@test.com',
    'paul@jackson.org
);

$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->addTo($toEmail)
    ->getTransport();

if(!empty($bcc)) {
    foreach ($bcc as $emailBcc) {
        $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($emailBcc);
    }
}

$transport->sendMessage();
```